# Having Trouble updating a chart Series using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-charts

Pretty much I've written a function that when run goes and fetches the most recent data from another sheet and then goes about adjusting the series of a chart so that it graphs the last 6months worth of data. Every thing works until it gets to updating the Chart. I get

> Run-time error '438' Object doesn't support this property or method

Here's my code

```
Sub Update(startCell, data, sheet, charts, series)
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sheet).Activate
    Range(startCell).Select
    Do While (Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell))
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    Loop
    Dim x As Range
    Dim y As Range
    Dim NewRng As Range

    Set x = ActiveCell
    Set y = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -5)
    Set NewRng = Range(x.Address & ":" & y.Address)

    ActiveCell.Value() = data
    Worksheets(sheet).ChartObjects(charts).SeriesCollection(series).SetSourceData     Source:=NewRng.Address()


End Sub
```

Comment: .SetSourceData i think belongs to the Chart e.g. myChart.SetSourceData https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/chart-setsourcedata-method-excel

Comment: might it be something like Worksheets(sheet).ChartObjects(charts).SeriesCollection(1).XValues = NewRng.Value or as above in prior comment? Are charts and series parameters singular? So when used would be something like Chartobjects(Chart1), SeriesCollection(1) ........

Comment: Yes they're singular variables, the thing is the charts themselves contain multiple series being graphed therefore i have to do a seriesCollecetion

Also i tried the second meathod you posted Worksheets(sheet).ChartObjects(charts).SeriesCollection(1).X‌​Values = NewRng.Value same error

Comment: XValues is for the series labels.

Answer (score 0):

New Answer

Change variable names for sheet to sht, charts to cht and series to sers
Sheet, Charts and Series are all reserved words for VBA/Excel.

Make the NewRng a text variable that holds the sheet name and range

```
NewRng = "=" & sht & "!" & x.Address & ":" & y.Address

Worksheets(sht).ChartObjects(cht).Activate
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(sers).Values = NewRng
```

I scaled this down to :

```
Sheets(sht).ChartObjects(cht).Activate
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(sers).Values = "='" & sht & "'!" & ActiveCell.Address & ":" & ActiveCell.Offset(0, -5).Address
```

As long as sht get a value like 'Stewardship-Online', chart gets a text value of Graphique 3 and sers is an integer of 1 through 6 (you have 6 lines in your chart.

Comment: Might i ask what the diffrence is with FullSeriesCollection vs SeriesCollection? Because when i use FullSeriesCollection i get the error _Compile error: Method or data member not found_ and it highlights .FullSeriesCollection(sers) This might have something to do with me using Excel 2010 though

Comment: Also changing to .SeriesCollection gives me _Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error_

Comment: 2010... hmmm.  That could be the problem.  I am using 2016.  Is this a line chart, bar chart, etc?

Comment: Welcome to the life of a Government intern XD. lol its a basic line chart. with 6 data points. I just want to move the seires over to using the 6 most recent data points.

Comment: Could you try recording a macro while you change it manually?

Comment: Sub ChangeRange()
'
' ChangeRange Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Graphique 3").Activate
    ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = "='Stewardship-Online'!$AP$29:$AU$29"
End Sub


This is what i got so i how do i incorperate my variables into that? I tried doing this:

      Worksheets(sht).ChartObjects(cht).Activate
      ActiveChart.PlotArea.Select
      ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(sers).Values = "=sht NewRng"

Comment: This will get the address of the cell 5 columns to the left of the active cell (ActiveCell.Offset(0, -5)), is that what you want?  if active cell is x=AU29 then y is AP29 and the range needs to be AP29:AU29.  which is y.address & ":" & x.address.  You need to check all your variables to make sure they are getting the correct values you expect them to.

Comment: ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(sers).Values = NewRng, since you build this as a text variable.  See addition to answer